# Are \def and \define the same in ConTeXt?

Tags: context, context-mkiv

Is there any difference between defining a variable using `\def` and using `\define`, when used without a number inside square brackets, e.g. `\def\somecommand{\percent}` and `\define\somecommand{\percent}`? Can I always use `\define` in places where `\def` can be used?

Comment: From what I see, `\define\xyz{...}`, when `\xyz` is already defined issues a warning, but performs the definition anyway. Of course `\def` doesn't issue any warning.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For reference: There are two definitions of `\define`: The first one in
*syst-aux.mkiv* shows the behavior Egreg mentioned in his comment: if
the macro is already defined, it leaves it as it is. (A companion,
`\redefine` allows you to overwrite the current definition of macro
regardless of its being in use.) Ironically, this preliminary
definition is overwritten without note as soon as the format loads
*core-sys.mkiv* (while `\redefine` stays around forever).

The [actual definition](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/define)
of the `\define` macro as provided by the user interface does not only
check for previously defined control sequences of the same name, but
also serves as some kind of short notation for mandatory arguments.
It has the scheme

```
\define [<digit>] <macro> {<definition>}
```

where the first argument, a digit, specifies the number of arguments
the new macro is going to accept.  Obviously this can result in shorter
definitions. For comparison, the selector

```
\def\sevenofnine#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8#9{#7}
\starttext
\sevenofnine abcdefghi\par
\stoptext
```

requires some less typing with the `\define` macro:

```
\define[9]\sevenofnine{#7}
```

Thus these definitions may result in more readable code -- which is
always a good thing when writing TEX.

Unfortunately the `\define` wrapper takes away a good deal of the
expressiveness of plain `\def`’s. In Context, you will have noticed,
macros taking *optional arguments* are commonplace with respect to the
user inteface. For example you simply can’t replace the second
`\def`inition in below snippet with an equivalent expression using
`\define`:

```
\unprotect
\def\myfoo{\dosingleempty\do_my_foo}
\def\do_my_foo[#1]#2{%
  \iffirstargument{\bf\WORD#1}\fi
  #2\par%
}
\protect

\starttext
  \myfoo{bar}
  \myfoo[foo]{bar}
\stoptext
```

That’s because with `\define` you can’t specify the *argument
delimiters* (here: brackets) necessary for optional arguments, so
basically your macros are limited to taking mandatory (braced)
arguments only. For the same reason there is no way to define
cheap `\{start|stop}something` environments either:

```
\let\stopfoo\relax
\def\startfoo#1\stopfoo{\bgroup\bold#1\egroup}
%%%            ^^^^^^^^ not possible
\starttext
\startfoo
  bar
\stopfoo
\stoptext
```

(The user interface for this is `\definestartstop` (cf.
*core-sys.mkiv*), anyways.)

Finally, nowadays the most important drawback of `\define` is that it
does not allow for *mkvi*-style arguments. There is simply no way to
refer to a parameter by its *name* if you can’t assign it one in the
first place.

```
% macros=mkvi
\unprotect
\def\foo{\dosingleempty\do_foo}
\def\do_foo[#optional]#mandatory{%
  \bgroup\sansbold#optional\space\egroup
  #mandatory\par%
}
\protect

\starttext
  \foo{bar}
  \foo[foo]{bar}
\stoptext
```

So if you want to do some serious macro writing, you will soon learn to
avoid `\define`, while it is safe for less complex tasks.

Comment: Thank you for this helpful answer. Point of clarification: when you say "mkiv-style arguments", does that mean named arguments, like `#optional` in your example? Do you have a reference for where I can read more about those?

Comment: @LarsH Yes, Mk**VI** (not MkIV!) macros are the ones with (optional) parameter names.
I’m not sure there exists any user-level documentation besides the source: the preprocessor code can be found in [``luat-mac.lua``](http://repo.or.cz/w/context.git/blob/refs/heads/origin:/tex/context/base/luat-mac.lua) (for Context) and [``luatex-preprocessor.lua``](http://repo.or.cz/w/context.git/blob/refs/heads/origin:/tex/generic/context/luatex/luatex-preprocessor.lua) for Luatex-Plain.
Hth.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.

Comment: I don't know if this was the case at the time of writing this answer but today macros defined using `\define` are e-TeX protected.  To have it expandable one has to use `\defineexpandable` (or plain `\def`).