# Why can't we use a \define'd value as a parameter to \switchtobodyfont[...]?

Tags: macros, context-mkiv

This is a followup to the question [Are \def and \define the same in ConTeXt?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54788/are-def-and-define-the-same-in-context)

This snippet of code in mkiv ConTeXt (TeX Live 2013 version):

```
\define\smallfontsize{8.1pt}
\starttext
foo \switchtobodyfont[\smallfontsize] bar
\stoptext
```

gives the following output, including an error:

```
...
fonts           > bodyfont '\smallfontsize ' is defined (can better be done global)
fonts           > bodyfont '9.72pt' is defined (can better be done global)
fonts           > bodyfont '6.48pt' is defined (can better be done global)
! LuaTeX error [string "\directlua "]:1: invalid escape sequence near '\s'.

system          > tex > error on line 3 in file C:/Users/Huttar/Documents/work/tex/test-define.tex: LuaTeX error  ...

1     \define\smallfontsize{8.1pt}
2     \starttext
3 >>  foo \switchtobodyfont[\smallfontsize] bar
4     \stoptext
5     


\ctxcommand #1^^@-\directlua {commands.#1}

\font_helpers_low_level_define ..._designsize " )}
                                                  \edef \somefontspec {at \n...
\font_helpers_trigger_define ..._identifier_class 
                                                  \csname \v_font_identifier...
\applyfontclassstrategies ...\fontface \endcsname 
                                                  \else \expandafter \font_h...
\font_helpers_synchronize_font ...classstrategies 
                                                  \fi \setfalse \c_font_auto...
\rm f-\ifmmode \mathrm \else \normalrm 
                                       \fi 
...
l.3 foo \switchtobodyfont[\smallfontsize]
                                        bar
```

However if we change the `\define` at the beginning to `\def`, the error goes away.
The answer at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55778/6973, while helpful, only seems to describe the differences in terms of arguments to macros. In this case, where there are no arguments, why does `\switchtobodyfont[\smallfontsize]` fail when `\smallfontsize` is defined using `\define`? We would like to understand this better so we can avoid using `\define` in unsafe ways in the future.

A secondary question would be this (teach a man to fish!)... When confronted with the above error messages, we were at a loss to figure out what the problem was. The diagnostics didn't seem to point toward what the problem was, in a way we could understand. (It gave us the right line number, but the actual `\switchtobodyfont[\smallfontsize]` was buried a couple of macro invocations deep, along with a lot of other code.) We only figured out a solution because a colleague did a lot of trial-and-error commenting out code to find the offending line, and because we had run into a similar problem a long time ago. Is there something in that output that we can learn to interpret so that we could infer the cause and the solution of the problem? (Or could the diagnostic messages be improved to give a better clue to the cause?)

Comment: ``\define`` creates ``\unexpanded`` macros that interfere with the parser.
Also, the ``\{setup,switchto}bodyfont`` macros are known to have some quirks: http://wiki.contextgarden.net/unexpected_behavior#Treacherous_Dimensions

Comment: @phg: ok. I've been reading that wiki page section (which sounds like the title of a Charles Willams novel), but the quirk described there, namely the limitation that only integer sizes are reliable, doesn't seem to apply to this case. I don't understand how to tell that `\switchtobodyfont` needs to expand content and something else doesn't. But maybe I just need to avoid `\define`.

Answer (score 3):

The `\def` primitve creates expandable macros, or at least ones that will expand inside an `\edef` or `\csname`. On the other hand, `\define` uses `\protected\def` to create a protected macro. These *don't* expand inside `\csname`, and so are not suitable for use in anything that needs to expand content in this way. As such, you can't use `\define` for anything which might need to expand inside a `\cnsame` construct.  (Note: ConTeXt calls the `\protected` primitive `\unexpanded`, while I'm sticking to the primitive names.)

It's worth noting that this behaviour is deliberate: 'user commands' often are best made 'protected' as there are places where the lack of expansion is entirely the right thing to do.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. Can you give an example of when lack of expansion is the right thing to do? I think that will help me understand the contrast with `\switchtobodyfont[...]`, which requires the content to be expanded.

Comment: Can you point me to a reference for the `\protected` primitive? I don't see it at http://www.tug.org/utilities/plain/cseq.html#p-ai

Comment: @LarsH ``\protected`` (or it’s Context alias ``\unexpanded``) is described in the [ε-TeX](http://tug.ctan.org/systems/e-tex/v2/) manual (p. 14 of the PDF version, see also the [reference](http://tex.loria.fr/moteurs/etex_ref.html#protected)).