# How to specify [ and ] in a macro invocation in ConTeXt

Tags: macros, context

If have the following ConTeXt macros:

```
\def\tableHeader#1 {%
    \start
    \setupTABLE[frame=on,offset=1mm]
    \setupTABLE[c][1][width=0.25\textwidth]
    \setupTABLE[c][2][width=0.75\textwidth]
    \bTABLE
        \bTR
            \bTH[nc=2] #1 \eTH
        \eTR
}

\def\tableFooter {%
    \eTABLE
    \stop
}

\def\tableItem#1#2 {%
    \bTR
        \bTD #1 \eTD
        \bTD #2 \eTD
    \eTR
}
```

How do I call this macro with '[\w ]+' as second parameter? That is:

```
\tableHeader{Example}
\tableItem{Regex}{[\w ]+}
\tableFooter
```

Comment: I don't know much about context but I guess the space after `#2` in the definition might be a problem as well as using `\w` which looks like a macro but your input suggests it should be verbatim?

Comment: Yes, it should be verbatim. The second parameter is a regex pattern (including the space).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you want to ensure that `[` isn't seen as the start of an argument by `\bTD`. To do that, the easiest way is to insert a `\relax`. As you are making this part of a macro, I'd do that in the definition not each time you pass an argument

```
\def\tableItem#1#2 {%
    \bTR
        \bTD\relax #1 \eTD
        \bTD\relax #2 \eTD
    \eTR
}
\starttext
\bTABLE
\tableItem{Regex}{[\string\w\space]+}
\eTABLE
\stoptext
```

I suspect you want something like

```
\tableItem{Regex}{\type{[\w ]+}}
```

which would avoid the need for the `\relax` in this case as `\type` will also stop the scanning for a `[`, but it's likely best to keep the `\relax` anyway.

---

Working example using edited question: notice that `\w` has to be made into a string one way or another

```
\def\tableHeader#1 {%
    \start
    \setupTABLE[frame=on,offset=1mm]
    \setupTABLE[c][1][width=0.25\textwidth]
    \setupTABLE[c][2][width=0.75\textwidth]
    \bTABLE
        \bTR
            \bTH[nc=2] #1 \eTH
        \eTR
}

\def\tableFooter {%
    \eTABLE
    \stop
}

\def\tableItem#1#2 {%
    \bTR
        \bTD\relax #1 \eTD
        \bTD\relax #2 \eTD
    \eTR
}
\starttext
\tableHeader{Example}
\tableItem{Regex}{[\string\w\space]+}
\tableFooter
\stoptext
```

Comment: For me it doesn't work when I don't use the `\type`. Unfortunately the `\type` also makes the text mono-spaced.

Comment: @MartijnRijkeboer I though you might want `\type` as this looks to me like a situation where you'd expect mono-spaced: it was just a suggestion. However, the example without `\type` should work: certainly it does for me exactly as written with ConTeXt from TeX Live 2017. Can you elaborate (here or in the question) as to what 'doesn't work'?

Comment: I've added `\relax` to `\tableItem` as recommended. When I try to use `\tableItem{Regex}{[\w ]+}` I get `l.9 \tableFooter  <empty file>  ?`. I'm using ConTeXt from TeX Live 2016.

Comment: @MartijnRijkeboer Please make a full example and edit it into the question: I'm afraid I'll need more detail to help further. (For example, `\tableFooter` isn't a standard ConTeXt macro.)

Comment: I've updated the question, is this what you meant? I've let the `\relax` out, the keep the flow of the question and answer.

Comment: After trying some more, it seems that the `[` is working with `\relax`, but the  `\w` is the problem now.

Comment: @MartijnRijkeboer Yes, as I've mentioned you need to make it a string: TeX otherwise sees `\w` as an (unknown) control sequence.

Comment: @JosephWright You can use `\tex{w}` (or `\letterbackslash w`) to get text with a backslash in front of it.

Comment: @Metafox I'm no ConTeXt expert, and `\string` does work here so I went with it :) (As I've said earlier, I'd expect to use `\type` for this situation anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

If you really to simply type `[\w ]+`, you can change the catcode table so that `\` is not a special character.

One way to do this is to use the `\tbacatcodes` catcode table (defined in `catc-ctx.mkiv`), that only sets the normal catcodes of `{` and `}`; everything else, including `\` has catcode `other`. Note that this means that you cannot use unmatched `{` and `}` inside the argument of `\tableItem`.

While I was at it, I also made a few stylistic changes to your code:

1. Use setups to setup table style
2. Use `\define` instead of `\def`. Keep in mind that space is significant in TeX, so `\def\tableItem#1#2 {` is different from `\def\tableItem#1#2{`.

The complete code is below

```
\startsetups regex-table
  \setupTABLE[frame=on,offset=1mm]
  \setupTABLE[c][1][width=0.25\textwidth]
  \setupTABLE[c][2][width=0.75\textwidth]
\stopsetups

\define[1]\tableHeader
  {\bTABLE[setups=regex-table]
    \bTR 
      \bTH[nc=2] #1 \eTH 
    \eTR}

\define\tableFooter{\eTABLE}

\define\tableItem
   {\pushcatcodetable
    \setcatcodetable\tpacatcodes
    \doTableItem}

\define[2]\doTableItem
   {\bTR
        \bTD\relax #1 \eTD
        \bTD\relax #2 \eTD
    \eTR
    \popcatcodetable}

\starttext
\tableHeader{Example}
\tableItem{Regex}{[\w ]+}
\tableFooter
\stoptext
```

Comment: What is the difference between `\def` and `\define`?

Comment: Nevermind, I found it on [tex.stackexchange.com](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54788/are-def-and-define-the-same-in-context)